# How to use C++14 with Xcode?

Tags: macos, clang, c++14

I just bought a macbook air,i installed Xcode but its not having c++ 14,i read some threads on stackoverflow and they are mentioning something like clang,what is clang and how do I complete this process??,please explain in layman terms,i am completely new to mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clang/LLVM are Macs' default compiler.

---

Now, about C++14:

> Clang has experimental support for some proposed features of the C++ standard following C++14, provisionally named C++1z. Note that support for these features may change or be removed without notice, as the draft C++1z standard evolves.
>
> You can use Clang in C++1z mode with the **-std=c++1z** option.

[from Clang/LLVM's documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html)

So just add "-std=c++1z" to your compile options in Xcode (without the quotes).

Comment: Do i need to separately install clang??...or does it gets installed with Xcode only?

Comment: To my knowledge, installing Xcode, also installs Xcode Command Line Tools -- which includes Clang/LLVM.  But if not, you can go into Applications > Utilities > Terminal and type in "clang". OSX will prompt you if you want to install Command Line Tools, select yes, and it will install Clang/LLVM.

Comment: Glad to help! If this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I was just now having the same problem. I found this in the build settings:
[image]

The drop-down menu has a C++14 option. It solved the problem for me.